# Why am I in danger of being blocked!? I have only ever asked 1 question and it has even recieved 1 upvote

Tags: discussion

Here's my history: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/3266/laggingreflex

I haven't deleted any questions either. The [deleted questions page](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/3266) is not visible to others so here's a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/J21aT.png

And here's the warning : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYpwd.png

Why has the system flagged me?

BTW it's only on fitness.stackexchange, other sites don't show me any warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've actually posted 3 questions, but only one is still open. The others were closed as a duplicate and as off-topic. I guess the system thinks 33% isn't a good rate...

[image]

Comment: [I sure haven't..](http://i.imgur.com/dboBKw1.png) Are you seeing a different version than what I'm seeing of my profile?

Comment: Er, sorry. 3 *questions* not 3 answers.

Comment: Thanks. Doh! x_x

Comment: Np. A couple  good questions/answers ought to fix that ratio